# Sharing External Hard drive on Network

Tags: windows-7, networking, hard-drive, permissions, external-hard-drive

I got problem when I try to share the external hard drive over the network. Basically the hard drive are connected using USB port and having 3 partition. My machine work on Windows 7.

When I accessing on another PC, I got Strange error 
[image]

I've using Advanced Sharing and check permission to `everyone` and also grant permission full control.

Also tried to take ownership to my current user and restart the pc also.

Is there anything I forgot? Kindly your help
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two measures might help here.
Long time since Windows 7, so I don't remember if one or both are enough.

**Everyone permissions for anonymous users**

- In the Start menu, enter *Edit group policy*
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Polices\Security Options*
- Find and double-click
  *Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users*
- Set it to *Enabled* and click OK.

**Enable the Guest account and give permissions on the share**

- In the Start menu, enter *User Accounts*
- Click on *Manage another account*
- Click *Guest*
- You will be presented with the question
  *Do you want to turn on the guest account?*
- Click *Turn on*
- Now that it is enabled, give the Guest account all permissions on the share.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps below to share the external hard drive to the network and, for your particular error, please cross check the permission setting on Step 8:

[image: Permission Setting]

Taken from [Adding an external hard drive to your network](https://www.linksys.com/id/support-article?articleNum=138002):

> Step 1: Connect the external hard drive to the USB port of your server or computer that is always ON.
>
> **IMPORTANT**:  Take note of your server or computer’s IP Address as it will be used to map the shared hard drive on your network.
>
> Step 2: Click the Start button, then click Computer.  The external hard drive should be displayed.
>
> Step 3: Right-click on the external drive, then select Share with.  Click Advanced sharing….
>
> Step 4: Click the Advanced Sharing… button.
>
> Step 5: Check the Share this folder option.  Click Add and then
>   enter a name for the folder or drive you want to share.
>
> **NOTE**:  In this example, Shared_Storage is entered as the name of the external hard drive.
>
> Step 6: Click the Permissions button.
>
> Step 7: Select
>   the Everyone option.  This drive will be accessible to everyone connected to your network.
>
> Step 8: Check the Allow boxes next to Full Control, Change or Read option.
>
> Step 9: Click the Apply button and then click OK to close the User Settings window.
>
> Step 10: Click OK to close the Permission window.
>
> Step 11: Click Close to exit the Advanced Sharing window.

Comment: Link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken.
Can you elaborate on this a little more?

Comment: Thanks Toto for the guidance, amended accordingly. Thanks again.

Comment: @Greenonline good edit, well done

Comment: You _must_ include the link from which you took your information from, otherwise the post _will_ be deleted for plagiarism. I have amended your post for you accordingly.